# How to Get Value Using Angularjs Through Class or Tagname?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to javascript and angular  so,not familiar with trivial manipulation, How can I get value using angularjs through class or tagname? Also plz have a look at below two pictures-

[image]

After some time there is a change-

[image]

Now  some attributes in below `HTML` code has same attribute, -

```
<input type="text"
       class="menuTitleField ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-valid-required" 
       ng-model="title" placeholder="Option Name" elastic-input=""
       ng-required="isRequired" focus-on="newChild" focus-if="canFocus"
       tabindex="0" required="required" style="min-width: 0px; width: 48px;">
```

I think values of `canFocus`and`title `` come from the sever, how can I get values of those attribute?

Now I want to get value of `canFocus` and `title`, through class name or tag name or event.target.id, how can I get that?

Plz, ask in comment for clarification, also  edit the post  for more precise question. thanks.

Comment: Please share the html that surrounds the `input` element you're interested in. There needs to be enough information to specify exactly the element, and because there is no `id` on the `input`, then we should look to the ancestor elements for `id`.  Alternatively, are there any other `input` elements with `class="menuTitleField"`?